# chartjs config options and annotation

Tags: annotations, chart.js

Line chart with annotation plugin and options for line chart: cant get working both, just either options: annotation or options: scales: {...}

Commenting the options for the line chart 'aspentRation etc.etc.' the rquired color block between 42 and 50 is visible.
Including the variable chartPlugins no color block is visible.

This is what I want:
[Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Tgd.jpg)
Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ChartT1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="TC1">
    <canvas id="ChartT1"></canvas>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@^3'></script>

<script>

var wwtemp   = [ 42.2, 42.4, 43.2, 45.1, 46.5, 48.7, 49.4, 50.5, 49.9, 49.2 ];
var tempdata = [ 12.3, 13.5, 14.6, 15.3, 16.3, 15.3, 14.6, 13.7, 11.8, 10.7 ];
var timeaxis = ['12:10','12:15','12:20','12:25','12:30','12:35','12:40','12:45','12:50','12:55'];

const <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ChartT1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="TC1">
    <canvas id="ChartT1"></canvas>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@^3'></script>

<script>

var wwtemp   = [ 42.2, 42.4, 43.2, 45.1, 46.5, 48.7, 49.4, 50.5, 49.9, 49.2 ];
var tempdata = [ 12.3, 13.5, 14.6, 15.3, 16.3, 15.3, 14.6, 13.7, 11.8, 10.7 ];
var timeaxis = ['12:10','12:15','12:20','12:25','12:30','12:35','12:40','12:45','12:50','12:55'];

const chartPlugins = {
    plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        box1: {
          type: 'box',
          yMin: 42,
          yMax: 50,
          borderWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(204, 255, 153, 0.3)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}   // chartPlugins */

const chartConfig = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: timeaxis,
        datasets: [ {
            label: 'Temperature (°C)',
            data: tempdata,
            borderColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line', // Set point style to 'line'
            radius: 0,          // no point
        },
        {
            label: 'WW-Temp (°C)',
            data: wwtemp,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line', // Set point style to 'line'
            radius: 0,          // Set point
        } ],
    },
    options: chartPlugins,
/***    options: {
        chartPlugins,
        responsive: true,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        scales: {
            x: { title: { },
                ticks: { maxRotation: 80,
                         minRotation: 80,
                },
            },
            y: { beginAtZero: false,
                 min: -10,
                 max: 60,
                ticks:{ stepSize: 10, }
            }
        }, 
    }, ***/
}
// Show chart
const ctx = document.getElementById('ChartT1').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);

</script>

</body>
</html>

= {
    plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        box1: {
          type: 'box',
          yMin: 42,
          yMax: 50,
          borderWidth: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(204, 255, 153, 0.3)'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}   // chartPlugins */

const chartConfig = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: timeaxis,
        datasets: [ {
            label: 'Temperature (°C)',
            data: tempdata,
            borderColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line', // Set point style to 'line'
            radius: 0,          // no point
        },
        {
            label: 'WW-Temp (°C)',
            data: wwtemp,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line', // Set point style to 'line'
            radius: 0,          // Set point
        } ],
    },
    options: chartPlugins,
/***    options: {
    chartPlugins,
    responsive: true,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        scales: {
        x: { title: { },
            ticks: { maxRotation: 80,
                    minRotation: 80,
                },
            },
            y: { beginAtZero: false,
                 min: -10,
                 max: 60,
        ticks:{ stepSize: 10, }
            }
        }, 
    }, ***/
}
// Show chart
const ctx = document.getElementById('ChartT1').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, see:  [image: With 1 horizontal bar]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ChartT1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div  id="TC1">
    <canvas id="ChartT1" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@^3'></script>

<script>

var wwtemp   = [ 42.2, 42.4, 43.2, 45.1, 46.5, 48.7, 49.4, 50.5, 49.9, 49.2 ];
var tempdata = [ 12.3, 13.5, 14.6, 15.3, 16.3, 15.3, 14.6, 13.7, 11.8, 10.7 ];
var timeaxis = ['12:10','12:15','12:20','12:25','12:30','12:35','12:40','12:45','12:50','12:55'];
var tempaxis = [ -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60 ];

var dw = window.innerWidth ||
         document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var dh = window.innerHeight||
         document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.body.clientHeight;
var ratio = dw/dh;

const box1 = {
    type: 'box',
    yMin: 42,
    yMax: 50,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(204, 255, 153, 0.20)',
};  // box1
const box2 = {
    type: 'box',
    yMin: -0,
    yMax: -10,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(000, 000, 255, 0.025)',
};  // box2
 

const chartConfig = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: timeaxis,
        datasets: [ {
            label: 'Temperature (°C)',
            data: tempdata,
            borderColor: 'blue',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line',
            radius: 0,
        },
        {
            label: 'WW-Temp (°C)',
            data: wwtemp,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointStyle: 'line', // Set point style to 'line'
            radius: 0,          // Set point
        } ],
    },  // data
    options: {
        plugins: {
            annotation: {
            drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
            annotations: [ box1, box2 ],
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        aspectRatio: ratio,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        scales: {
            x: { title: { },
                ticks: { maxRotation: 45,
                        minRotation: 45,
                },
            },
            y: { beginAtZero: false,
                min: -10,
                max: 60,
                ticks:{ stepSize: 5, }
            }
        },
    },  // options
};  // chartConfig

const ctx = document.getElementById('ChartT1').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).